# Notificar en el template de django el duplicate key

Tags: django

Tengo un modelo de una factura que lleva los fields de serie y numero, ambos tienen que ser únicos en el modelo en la clase Meta tengo:

```py
unique_together=['serie','numero']
```

necesito ayuda a la hora de tratar estos errores en el template para que me notifique esto para poder cambiar y así cumplir con esa validación

Answer (score 0):

Esa operación ya debería devolver un error interno del servidor al *template*, por lo que podrías capturar ese caso.

Sin embargo, si quieres lograr un error más detallado, la lógica de validación que describes puede ir en la vista de dicho modelo. Esto dado que en este lugar se puede configurar una respuesta más estructurada que pueda leer el *front-end* de tu aplicación. Haciendo una validación de la entrada, en este caso al crear una instancia de Factura, se puede retornar una respuesta con más detalles como un mensaje que diga, por ejemplo:

> Este par (serie, numero) ya existe al crear una Factura